# Setting the default resolution/scaling of the login screen in FileVault enabled systems (macOS Sierra)

Tags: macos, filevault, resolution, login-screen

The login screen has a default scaling that is set when you boot up. Once booted though, it will adopt the scaling of whatever user was last logged in. I've heard the default scaling can be set by setting the scaling of the root user, but this has not worked for me. My best guess is that this is due to FileVault being enabled. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: From what I found out, FileVault changes the boot disk to the Recovery HD, and when you boot it just offers your logins that are read from the normal HD. I don't think it's able to view your settings, since the main HD that has your settings is encrypted.

Comment: Doesn't it still have to pull information about how to scale the display from _somewhere_?